# C# Completely run async method with EndInvoke without Application.DoEvents

Tags: c#, async-await, invoke

I am running into a problem with the following code:

```
private int check = 1;

private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task AsyncMethod()
{
    check = 2;
    await ...;
    check = 3;
}

private void Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var invoke = this.BeginInvoke(async x =>
    {
        await AsyncMethod();
    });
    Debug.WriteLine("1: " + check);
    EndInvoke(invoke);
    Debug.WriteLine("2: " + check);
    Application.DoEvents();
    Debug.WriteLine("3: " + check);
}
```

I want to end `AsyncMethod` immediately and entirely whenever I run `EndInvoke`. However, it returns:

```
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
```

whereas I expect it to return `2: 3`. Is there a way to do this without `Application.DoEvents` (as I want to avoid using that as much as possible)?

EDIT: After further testing, it seems like `Application.DoEvents` works best in this situation. It even works when `AsyncMethod` contains multiple `await` calls; all of those are run when running `Application.DoEvents` after `EndInvoke`.

Comment: Brr, what wonky webs we weave.  BeginInvoke runs its target on the UI thread, but it is called from code that already runs on the UI thread.  So cannot execute until the code explicitly yields back to the dispatcher loop.  So nothing can *start* to happen until you call EndInvoke.  If you expect the async method to be completed then it just isn't async anymore and there is no point to writing such code.

Comment: The reason why I even want to use EndInvoke is because lots of data is being loaded using BeginInvoke calls on several methods and the resulting IAsyncResults are stored. Then for some operations I must end all the methods that have been started using BeginInvoke, which I do using EndInvoke on all IAsyncResults. This works well (i.e. it runs the code completely) unless the method has an await call, which is necessary on certain occasions. Therefore I would like it to work in those situations as well.

Comment: Async code is useful to prevent the UI from freezing.  Doing it this way just makes that a lot worse.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is cancellation, cancellation can only be done cooperatively in .NET.

[Here is a article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) from Microsoft's documentation that explains the process to make your tasks/threads cancellable. But the short version is you will need to pass in to the function a `CancellationToken` and check it throughout the method to cancel the code.

```
private int check = 1;

private async Task AsyncMethod(CancellationToken token)
{
    check = 2;
    await Task.Delay(5000, token); //Wait for 5 seconds or till the token is signaled.
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    check = 3;
}

//Event handlers like this is the only place you are allowed to do async void
private async void Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("1: " + check);
    try
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = AsyncMethod(cts.Token); //Start the task
        cts.Cancel();
        await task; //Wait for the task to finish or throw a OperationCanceledException
        Debug.WriteLine("2: " + check);
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException)
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("3: " + check);
}
```

The above will output

```
1: 1
3: 2
```

Comment: This code does not run `AsyncMethod` using `BeginInvoke`, which is the case in my program.

Comment: Yes, but it does call AsyncMethod without awaiting it immediately which has the fairly similar behavior if you are on the UI thread and AsnycMethod is well behaved.